# Auto string merging in Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have new string from file ("new.dat") to be merge with file ("old.dat").

```
File : "new.dat"
WBGG 120200Z VRB03KT 9000 FEW015 BKN160 28/25 Q1013 NOSIG

File : "old.dat"
WBGG 120130Z VRB02KT 9000 FEW015 BKN150 27/25 Q1013 NOSIG    
WBGG 120100Z VRB02KT 9999 FEW014 BKN150 26/25 Q1012 NOSIG
```

The expected output will overwrite and became new ("old.dat")

```
WBGG 120200Z VRB03KT 9000 FEW015 BKN160 28/25 Q1013 NOSIG
WBGG 120130Z VRB02KT 9000 FEW015 BKN150 27/25 Q1013 NOSIG    
WBGG 120100Z VRB02KT 9999 FEW014 BKN150 26/25 Q1012 NOSIG
```

The process will continue as the new string in "new.dat" appeared in the system. The result from the current script is weird. Anyone got ideas?

```
new=open("new.dat","r")
old=open("old.dat","r")

for line1 in new:
    data1=line1

for line2 in old:
    data2=line2   

newdata=np.array([data1,data2])

## overwrite file and become old file
newfile = open("old.dat", 'w')
newfile.write(newdata)
newfile.close()
```

Comment: If you are going to use np, you might aswell go for reading the files with np. Concatenate or vstack seems right way to go.

Comment: Please explain what is the "result from the current script" instead of just "weird".

Comment: Also please have [tag:python-3.x] or [tag:python-2.7] too.

Comment: I used python-2.7...the weird output is ignoring line no. 2. WBGG 120130Z....is missing..

Comment: it just saved line 1 and 3 only..

Comment: @AntonBR..I tried using concatenate but I dont know how to handle the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant with "sticking to numpy":

```
a = np.loadtxt('old.dat', dtype='object')
b = np.loadtxt('new.dat', dtype='object')

c = np.vstack((b,a))

np.savetxt('old.dat', c, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Or you could use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.concat((pd.read_csv(i, sep=' ', header=None) for i in ('new.dat', 'old.dat')))
    .to_csv('old.dat', sep=' ', index=False, header=None))
```

But I would probably use some shell script for this. Windows for instance (type this into terminal in the folder)

```
(type old.dat new.dat) >> old.dat
```

Comment: ...it woroks..great. I am so happy for that...yess!!...but how to make sure the recent new data is place on top??

Comment: @Azam You change the order of (a,b) to (b,a)

Comment: I did not know vstack is helpful in here...thanks again @Anton vBR

Comment: what if the data in different dimension or columns?. how to combine it..

Comment: the above example was in exact column hence no problem to use vstack...@Anton vBR

Comment: @Azam Show us a small example.

Comment: ...please go to this topic. I put on once again the details regarding the example : "Merging Different Dimension or Column of String Using Vstack Python"

Comment: @Azam Entered it but seems like you got that answered too. Great!

Answer (score 1):

We can use append for writting new data to the old file ,as new data becomes old data for next incoming New data . Try to change

```
newfile = open("old.dat", 'w')
```

To

```
newfile = open("old.dat", 'a')
```